# how to customise animation(segue) between 2 table views in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiviewanimation

**Background:** I have table 1 and table 2 in the app, 
the start view is table 1,

**What to implement:**  user swipe right, then the view slide from left to right and shows table 2

**My method:**

1. I tried add segue between table 1 and table 2, and using push style, the problem is, table 2 is always slide from right to left, so I drop this method
2. customise animation: I added customized segue and indeed, I can see the transition from left to right when user swipe to right. The problem is: table 2 just shows once and it becomes black screen.

My customised segue code is as below:

```
    UIViewController* source = (UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController* destination = (UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController;
    CGRect sourceFrame = source.view.frame;
    sourceFrame.origin.x = sourceFrame.size.width;

    CGRect destFrame = destination.view.frame;
    destFrame.origin.x = -destination.view.frame.size.width;
    destination.view.frame = destFrame;

    destFrame.origin.x = 0;

    [source.view.superview addSubview:destination.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         source.view.frame = sourceFrame;
                         destination.view.frame = destFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         UIWindow *window = source.view.window;
                         [window setRootViewController:destination];
                     }];
```

I suspect it is due to the completion code:  **window setRootViewController:destination** because table 1 and 2 are using **uitableviewcontroller** instead of **uiviewcontroller**, 
I have tried to change uiviewcontroller in above code to uitableviewcontroller, but it still does not work.

Any body knows how to solve this? 
Source code can be downloaded here http://d.pr/f/tAkc

Comment: I think your problem is with your second tableView. Have you storyboard?
Show your code for second tableView (viewDidLoad)...

Comment: the second table view is showing properly if the is no customised segue, your can find the source code from  http://d.pr/f/tAkc which include all the code, take a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:
The solution is removing the navigation controller in the source code.

I added navigation controller in the beginning due to using push segues(swip left/right to backward/forward), When I try customised segue animation, navigation controller is still there.

Anyway, here is the final source code http://d.pr/f/ewOa , you can swipe left/right from table view 1 to 2 and without crash.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

So.. sorry for my answer before, but i can't put comments with my actual reputation.

The problem with black view after you push that view to another is in your segue.

try to delete this code :

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     UIWindow *window = source.view.window;
                     [window setRootViewController:destination];
```

If i delete it, segue is complete and second table is still there, but another problem is that you are not able to swipe back to first table.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tried deleted this before, then every time I swipe back, it crashes :(

Comment: I just tried bookmarks that and on this code app turn black. But i dont saw code for swipe back. It must be implemented in your tableView2.m file.

Comment: Hi Mayo, I have attached a new source code with swipe back in tableview 2: http://d.pr/f/YUqW  and as we expected, it crashes every time. One thing to take note is that if you change tableview 1 and 2 to normal uiview 1 and 2, the method we tried is perfectly fine and works well. I scratch my head and still don't know the root cause

Comment: Hi Mayo, fyi refer my above comments for the answer.